# Trying to retrieve first string from PubNub history Response

Tags: arrays, pubnub

I know that the response from the pubnub `history()` is:

```
[["message","Message","message"],"Start Time Token", "End Time Token"]
```

im creating an string to receive the response:

```
String msg = response.toString();
```

And this should give me the full array, but now to retrieve the first message im doing this:

```
String[] msgOne = msg[0];
```

And this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for pubnub history method ,  the response is a org.json.JSONArray so to get the messages array you can use something like this.

```
JSONArray messages = (JSONArray)( ((JSONArray)response).get(0));
```

`JSONArray` class here http://www.json.org/javadoc/ provides more info about the methods that you can use on messages variable.